# How to replace on old 2 wire single light switch with a 3 wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring

This house is over 100 years old and we don't know when this very old light switch was put in. The actual outside switch just broke right off yesterday.  All of the new replacements have 2 wires on one side and 1 on the other side. This one only has 2 black wires, one on either side. How do we replace it with a modern switch? Thx so much.

Comment: Can you take a few pictures of the box  and switch?

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the situation? Also, does your new switch have ON and OFF marked on it?

Comment: First rule of switches, is never, never, ever think about "positions" of screws.  Whether they're on opposite sides, same side, it's all the same.  What matters is the *functions* of the screws - what they do. That is revealed by screw color, lettering, etc.   So to get right to that point: **Is one of the 3 screws *GREEN?***

Comment: Yes, the broken off switch does say on and off, and the new switch box has a green screw, but not the old one being replaced. Yes, will post pics, thx, just figured how to add them.

Comment: As @Harper-ReinstateMonica was hinting at, your _new_ switch has screws for the hot (the switch breaks the connection in the hot wire to stop or allow the flow of electricity), _and_ it has that _green_ screw to allow the switch itself to be grounded. Your _old_ switch (like most of mine) has screws for the hot side of the circuit, and does _not_ have a grounding contact for the switch itself. You probably will _not_ find a ground wire (bare copper or green or green/yellow jacket) in the box, either.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you, everyone. The solution was to remove the black wires from the old switch and simply attach them to the two screws on the right side of the new switch (doesn't matter which one attached to the top screw or the bottom screw), and that's it. In the very back of this particular box, there is a brass screw with wires attached that are crimped and have a screwed on end on them. So in this case, the box is already grounded. Thank you again. What an excellent resource.

Comment: Good deal. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what to do next. You'll need to provide and accept an answer.

Comment: @TheTanners -- if you can provide that as the answer, I'll give you a +1 for it :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Your original switch sounds like a single pole single throw (on off). Your new switch sounds like a single pole double throw (referred to as a 3 way)

You can make this switch work by connecting 1 of the wires to the black screw. Then the other wire to one of the 2 other screws (notice a 3 way has no on off) turn the power back on and see if up on, if correct turn power back off and push switch back in, if backwards decide which would be better.

Turn switch and stuff it back in or move the 2nd wire (not black screw) to the other terminal. With old wiring I prefer to not twist the wires as the insulation may be brittle so moving the conductor over to the other connector may be best, then push it in and tighten.